# How to determine Drop event in DragSource

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-and-drop

I have a Listbox, that contains some text values

```
<ListBox x:Name="DragSource" PreviewMouseMove="DragSource_OnPreviewMouseMove" SelectedValuePath="Content">
  <ListBoxItem>first</ListBoxItem>
  <ListBoxItem>second</ListBoxItem>
 </ListBox>
```

and event handler

```
private void DragSource_OnPreviewMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
 if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed && DragSource.SelectedItem != null)
 {
  var data = new DataObject(DataFormats.Serializable, DragSource.SelectedItem);
  var value = (string)DragSource.SelectedValue;
  data.SetData(DataFormats.Text, value);
  var de = DragDrop.DoDragDrop(DragSource, data, DragDropEffects.All);
 }
}
```

Items can be dropped to my other ListBox or into other application like Word or Excel. How i can detect that text was dropped (for example in Word) and delete ListBoxItem if DragDrop effect is "Move"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No 3rd party app is going to tell you that it moved your ListBoxItem.  At best it will use the text representation and tell you it copied.  Getting a move requires a drop target that can recognize your object in its DragEnter event handler and decide that it can take responsibility for it.  Only you could write such an event handler.

Comment: My dragsource have GiveFeedback and QueryContinueDrag events, where i can find out what effects is now applying.
QueryContinueDragEventArgs has action that can be Cancel, Drop or Continue. But i receive only Continue event.

Comment: QCD is only there to allow you to change the D+D when the keyboard or mouse state changed.  Yes, Action is set to Continue because that's the default.  Assigning it ends the D+D.